# What's a good Flash game development tutorial, in FlashDevelop, for an absolute beginner?

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

Ok, here's my situation: I'm tutoring a 14yo homeschooled student with very little previous programming experience, and I'd like to teach her how to program.  I think that Flash Actionscript 3 is a good resource for her to start out with, mostly because she seems to have an interest in game development.

I've decided that FlashDevelop, used alone, is the best interface for her to use, especially as she becomes more proficient in Flash.  The trouble is, while I am an extremely competent Web programmer in other languages, I have no experience with Actionscript at all, and I can't find a good tutorial for her to use.

The tutorial doesn't need to have the algorithmical basics of programming, like the concept of loops, if statements, OOP, etc; I can teach her those.  What I need is a tutorial that teaches Actionscript SYNTAX and walks you through the steps of game development in FlashDevelop.  Once I have that, I can do everything else.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: flash is dead and Actionscript is an horrible pseudo-language, if i was you I would go for a mobile platform or for something like WebGL.

Comment: @user827992 Flash being dead is only true for mobile devices where Adobe stopped further development of the flash player. On desktop systems it's still ubiquitous and also: Actionscript is a dialect of ECMAScript, eg. it's a superset of JavaScript... the same you would use in a WebGL application. Then again Actionscript supports several OOP features (Classes, Interfaces, Properties, etc.) which JavaScript doesn't, so it makes it a good candidate to learn OOP principles.

Comment: @bummzack we can browse the history of Actionscript on every random wiki, the problem is that AS can only aspire to become a language like javascript, it's the worst language that i have ever used, for teaching purposes is just a nightmare and you are going to teach things in the worst possible way if you are using AS as first language. The latest version of AS stil doesn't even have a basic check like the one about buffer overflow that exist in all AS versions and is a serious bug that is still there. AS is horrible, the only reason why it works is that the flash plugin is full of patch.

Comment: by the way Adobe also dropped the support for Flash for the Linux desktop versions, not only Android. It's just dead, if you want to wait for an official statement is fine, but teaching AS or Flash today is like wasting your time for something that will never become something useful at all.

Comment: @user827992 Maybe you could base your statements on facts? Who says teaching AS as first language is the "worst possible way" (except you of course)? Also bugs in the VM aren't a problem of the programming language. That's like saying Java is bad when there's a bug in the VM. Or JavaScript is bad when Microsoft has a JS Bug in IE. You can't be seriously advertising JavaScript to learn OOP principles... but [HAXE](http://haxe.org/) could be a good alternative to AS (but it's harder to get learning resources as it's less common than ActionScript).

Comment: @bummzack show me how to prevent a buffer overflow in an AS version of your choice. Even if you can prove that ( and you can't ) why teaching a dead technology? Teaching Pascal these days makes more sense.

Comment: @user827992 : i think that when you start a new language, it does not matter if one is better than another, you just want to create something, if you want to make a game, even a simple one, Flash is a good option. When i started programming, i was frustrated with Java or C, then Java for android, i found it boring to create apps. I finally headed to the game development, and i am happy with it, with Cocos2d or Unity. Programming can be boring, and using a soft like Flash can change everything. At least, it makes the learning curve more fun.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback.

@Paul: You hit the nail on the head.  When you're just learning programming, pretty much any language is good enough.  I know Flash has some problems - all languages do - but it's great for creating simple games.  Unity is also a great resource, but it's complicated as heck.  Same for languages like Lua, etc.  Flash seems to be the simplest platform, so I'll use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with a game, i think it is the best solution to learn :
you will find some examples here :

[35-flash-game-development](http://pelfusion.net/35-flash-game-development-tutorials-fla-files/)

and this one especially is good to learn :

[avoider game tutorial](http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2008/09/17/avoider-game-tutorial-1/)

Comment: The 35 game dev tutorials look awesome.  However, I found that avoider game tutorial, and rejected it, mostly because it uses Adobe Flash Professional, or whatever it's called, not FlashDevelop.

Comment: @user1544712 : okay, good luck with the tutorials, for FlashDevelop, i think you can use the objects on stage by "exporting them for AS3" (when you create a movieclip on stage, >Library >Property) and in your .as file, you just "type" the variable with the name you wrote in the property (ex: `var myExemple:Example = new Example();`) then you can use "myExample" to move it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To get familiar with the Flash Develop IDE:
http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/beginners-guide-to-flashdevelop-intro-basix/

As Paul suggested, the avoider game tutorial is great.

Comment: That also looks great, but don't you think that the text is screwy?  It doesn't wrap the text when paragraphs get long; you have to scroll to the side to see it all.

I'll be using both of these.  Thank you two so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The most comprehensive guide I've seen so far is [this one](http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-learn/how-to-learn-flash-and-as3-for-game-development/) from [GamedevTuts+](http://gamedev.tutsplus.com). It gives you a complete overview of Flash gamedev, pointing out very interesting tutorials and resources.